Movie where the guy kills his pregnant girlfriend and gets away with it
The guy is having the ambition of getting into a wealthy family. He gets involved with rich girl. He also has girlfriend which is pregnant. He kills her on the doorstep and the landlord lady sees him, but some guy gets accused because he had some stolen property that belonged to this murdered girl. The detective lets the guy walk and lets him. There are actually 2 detectives and one of them is sure that the guy is guilty. Famous cast and yet I cannot remember the movie`s title or the actors. Total blackout and I am struggling all day! Help!

Could be Match Point

Match Point is a 2005 crime romantic drama film. Rhys Meyers's character marries into a wealthy family, but his social position is threatened by his affair with his brother-in-law's girlfriend.





Yes, that is IT!!! Thank you so much!

No problem, glad I could help!
